# Signed AIR package vs Signed Native Installer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Im using Flex SDK 4.6 and Flashbuilder 4.6. On windows 7.
If I create a signed native installer, it installs and runs just fine.
If I create a signed air package, it installs but appears to run (i see the process in task manager) but I dont see anything, like it is running invisible.
Anyone got any idea how to troubleshoot this? what could be the cause?
If .air is supposed to run on any PC with AIR runtime, why do we need native installers?
(plain native installer and not the captured runtime). Any tips?

Comment: Adobe Native Extensions only work if you use a native installer - they dont work if installing with an .air file. There may be other reasons for going native (other than 'ease' of installing), but im not aware of any.

Comment: One reason for using Native Installers is to hide the dependency on the AIR Runtime being installed.  Your app is "self contained" in essence and can be run anywhere.

Comment: i did say "...other than 'ease' of installing..."

Comment: Ahh, so the main reason of having a native installer is because of ANE's? because I remembered that im using a 3rd party app (with exe file) reponsible for doing license activation. so in short, if I want an .air package, I need to convert the 3rd party app into an ANE. correct?